# What is the methodID for SafeMath function when SafeMath library is referenced internally?

Tags: evm, bytecode

For the contract below

```
contract Example
{
    using SafeMath for uint256;

    uint256 internal _amount;

    function example(uint256 amount)
    external
    {
        _amount = _amount.add(amount);
    }
}
```

after compiling to EVM bytecode, the SafeMath.add(uint256,uint256) should appear defined in the code.

anyone knows how to calculate the keccak256() signature for this function?
what should I look for in the contract bytecode?